Why does the alpha particle have zero spin?
Wouldn't it have multiple total spin quantum number possibilities by spin addition of the 4 nucleons it is composed of? Why is it specifically zero? I get that they would behave as bosons due to being composed of four spin-1/2 fermions, thus resulting in 0, 1 or 2 spin. However, I don't understand how angular momentum addition comes into this.

Because of how nucleons fill orbitals. It's like why a beryllium atom's electrons' spins cancel.

To a first approximation, the alpha particle has zero spin because the only bound $ppnn$ state  has spins $p\uparrow p\downarrow n\uparrow n\downarrow$ with zero orbital angular momentum (S-state).
Any other S-state arrangement of spins requires either the two protons or the two neutrons to have parallel spins, so the Pauli Exclusion Principle forces one of the nucleons into a higher orbital momentum state. Putting any of the nucleons into such a higher orbital state requires more energy than the alpha particle binding energy, so the excited state would immediately decay with the nucleon escaping.
More precisely, according to the Table of Nuclides, the neutron binding energy in a $^4$He nucleus (alpha particle) is $20578$ keV and the proton binding energy is $19814$ keV.  The lowest energy $^4$He$^*$ spin-1 state has an excitation energy of $23640$ keV with a half-life of $7.4\times 10^{-23}$ seconds, and the lowest energy spin-2 state has an excitation energy of $21840$ keV with a half-life of $22.7\times 10^{-23}$seconds.
This is related to "Why don't neutrons and protons have variable half-integer spin?".
Note added: As several comments have noted, there is likely some S-D mixing in the $^4$He wave function (e.g. up to $10$% according to Doma & El-Gendy 2018).  This means there is a small contribution from D-states where all four nucleons have parallel spins but this is cancelled out by opposite $l=2$  orbital angular momentum.  This does not affect the general point that all $^4$He$^*$ states with spin greater than zero are unbound, but the full theoretical understanding is a bit messier than my simple S-state explanation above.

I would not call those non-zero spin states excited alpha particles, rather $^4{\rm He}^*$..excited helium nuclei. Also by $N\uparrow N\downarrow$, you mean $|NN\rangle|\uparrow\downarrow-\downarrow\uparrow)\rangle \sqrt 2$

Thanks @JEB You are correct. I have tweaked my answer.

Great answer, @DavidBailey!

The current version of this answer (v2) ascribes a unique reality to the shell-model $s$-wave ground state (the one with zero orbital angular momentum) that I think is inappropriate. I would be stunned if the $d$-wave contribution to the helium ground state were exactly zero. The 4% $d$-wave admixture in the deuteron ground state was the first evidence that the nucleon-nucleon interaction has some tensor component; that same mechanism should produce similar admixtures in helium, which has more internal degrees of freedom. Perhaps relevant.

@rob I think I was an author on a $T20$ at J-Lab, and that sounds right. It was a long time ago, and I never got past $^3$He in my nuclear physics studies. I was wondering about the isospin state of He, too.

$\textrm{keV}$, not $\textrm{MeV}$, otherwise great answer.

Thanks @tobi_s for catching the MeV/keV typos. It is now fixed.

I would say it is related to Pauli's exclusion principle. An alpha particle is formed by two protons and two neutrons (both fermions). Since equal fermions cannot occupy equal quantum states, you need one of the protons and one of the neutrons to have spin 1/2, while the other proton and neutron have spin -1/2. This results in a net-spin value of zero. You could still have orbital angular momentum, but in processes that result in the emission of alpha-particles, those are generally ejected radially.

This is certainly not true: you can have $m=0$ states (i.e. spin $1/2$ and spin $-1/2$) with total spin $S=1$: $\vert 1,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert +\rangle \vert -\rangle + \vert -\rangle\vert+\rangle)$.  The eigenvalue $m$ is not enough to uniquely identify $S$
